# How do I open an udp socket for a multicastgroup with Qt?

Tags: qt, networking, udp, qtnetwork

I have a question about Qt & network sockets. If I have a computer with multiple IP-Adresses in different networks, how do I open an udp socket for a multicastgroup on a specific network-adapter/ip adress.

eg: ip `192.168.2.1` and `172.20.0.1` and I want to create a socket that receives packets from the multicast group `228.5.6.7` on the `172.20.0.1` network adapter.

Comment: FWIW, I've opened a bug on qt here: http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-8652

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set that in `imr_interface` as shown below: (probably it's set to `INADDR_ANY` now)

```
struct ip_mreq mreq;
mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("228.5.6.7");
mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr("172.20.0.1");// <---- right here
...
QSocketDevice* sdev = new QSocketDevice(QSocketDevice::Datagram);
...
setsockopt(sdev->socket(), IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,(const char *)&mreq, sizeof(struct ip_mreq));
...
```

Comment: I guess he is using the QT networking module and not raw operating system provided sockets (saves the slight differences in winsock if making cross platform app).

Comment: ewanm89: This is how you doit using Qt sockets. sdev is a QSocket device.

QSocketDevice* sdev = new QSocketDevice(QSocketDevice::Datagram);

Answer (score 0):

If it's a listening socket, you can use bind to IP address to bind it to a specific IP address to listen on.
If it's a client socket, the OS manage the right interface to create it on to reach that IP address as per routing table rules.

Comment: See yuriy's post http://www.qtcentre.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-3347.html

Yeah, can't set the multicast option in the QT api directly yet.